# Characteristic polynomial of a matrix of $1$'s

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, characteristic-polynomial, rank-1-matrices

I am trying to calculate the characteristic polynomial of the $n \times n$ matrix $A = \{ a_{ij} = 1 \}$.

- Case $n=2$: I obtained $p(\lambda)=\lambda^2-2\lambda$ .
- Case $n=3$: I obtained $p(\lambda)=-\lambda^3+3\lambda^2$.
- Case $n=4$: I obtained $p(\lambda)=\lambda^4 - 4\lambda^3$.

I guess that for the general case, we have

$$p(\lambda)=(-1)^n\lambda^{n}+(-1)^{n-1}n\lambda^{n-1}$$

I tried to use induction, but it didn't work, unless I've done wrong. Can somebody help me? Or give me a hint?

Comment: I think it's easier to just compute all of the eigenvalues. The eigenvectors are easy to write down. (Also, you should be using a definition of the characteristic polynomial that makes it monic.)

Comment: I really dont understand the problem, could any one explain me?

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2853981/find-the-eigenvalues-and-their-multiplicities-of-a-special-matrix?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 11):

Note that the matrix $$A = e e^T$$ where $e = \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\\vdots\\1\\1 \end{pmatrix}_{n \times 1}$.

Hence, $A^2 = \left(ee^T \right) \left(ee^T  \right)= e \left(e^T e \right) e^T = n ee^T = nA$.

This clearly indicates that the matrix is a rank one matrix. Hence it must have $n-1$ eigenvalues as $0$. The only non-zero eigen value if $\lambda =n$, since we have $\lambda^2 = n \lambda$ and $\lambda \neq 0$.

Answer (score 5):

The trace is $n$. The eigenvalue $0$ has multiplicity $n-1$. From this we can write down the characteristic polynomial without any computation.  Or else we can pick up the eigenvalue of $n$ by noting that the all $1$'s vector times our matrix  is the all $n$'s vector.

Comment: span of 17 seconds, you, Dennis, Marvis. I was going to answer, but.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma),

$$\det \left( s \, \mathrm I_n - \mathbb 1_n \mathbb 1_n^\top \right) = s^n \left( 1 - \frac{1}{s} \mathbb 1_n^\top \mathbb 1_n \right) = s^n - n s^{n-1} = s^{n-1} \left( s - n \right)$$

---

[linear-algebra](/questions/tagged/linear-algebra) [matrices](/questions/tagged/matrices) [determinant](/questions/tagged/determinant) [characteristic-polynomial](/questions/tagged/characteristic-polynomial)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Denote $v=(1,1,...,1)$ and $v_j=(1,0,..,0,-1,0,...,0)$ (all zeroes except for the first, where there is $1$ and the $j$th, where there is $-1$) (all column vectors). What happens when you multiply $A\cdot v$ and $A\cdot v_j$?

Answer (score 0):

We wish to compute the determinant of the $n\times n$ matrix
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}
1-\lambda&1&1&\cdots&1\\
1&1-\lambda&1&\cdots&1\\
1&1&1-\lambda&\cdots&1\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
1&1&1&\cdots&1-\lambda
\end{bmatrix}\tag1
$$
Here are two approaches, the second of which uses a generalization of the lemma cited in Rodrigo de Azevedo's answer.

---

**Finding a Similar Matrix**

Note that the $n-1$ dimensional subspace orthogonal to $\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&\cdots&1\end{bmatrix}^\text{T}$ is multiplied by $-\lambda$. (If the subspace is orthogonal to a given vector, we can subtract that vector from each row of the matrix when operating on that subspace.)

$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&\cdots&1\end{bmatrix}^\text{T}$ is multiplied by $n-\lambda$. (Just compute it.)

Thus, $M$ is similar to
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-\lambda&0&0&\cdots&0\\
0&-\lambda&0&\cdots&0\\
0&0&-\lambda&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots&n-\lambda\\
\end{bmatrix}\tag2
$$
Therefore,
$$
\det(M)=(-\lambda)^{n-1}(n-\lambda)\tag3
$$

---

**$\boldsymbol{\det(\lambda I_n-AB)=\lambda^{n-m}\det(\lambda I_m-BA)}$**

As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/94946),

> $$
> \det(\lambda I_n-AB)=\lambda^{n-m}\det(\lambda I_m-BA)\tag4
> $$

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&\cdots&1\end{bmatrix}^\text{T}$ and $B=A^\text{T}$, then $M=AB-\lambda I_n$.
Furthermore, $m=1$ and $BA=\begin{bmatrix}n\end{bmatrix}$.

$(4)$ then says that
$$
\begin{align}
\det(-M)
&=\det(\lambda I_n-AB)\tag{5a}\\[2pt]
&=\lambda^{n-1}\det(\lambda I_1-BA)\tag{5b}\\[2pt]
&=\lambda^{n-1}\det(\lambda I_1-\begin{bmatrix}n\end{bmatrix})\tag{5c}\\
&=\lambda^{n-1}(\lambda-n)\tag{5d}
\end{align}
$$
which, since $\det(-M)=(-1)^n\det(M)$, becomes
$$
\det(M)=(-\lambda)^{n-1}(n-\lambda)\tag6
$$