# Characteristic polynomial - using rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, characteristic-polynomial

Q:
Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix defined by $A_{ij}=1$ for all $i,j$.
Find the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

There is probably a way to calculate the characteristic polynomial $(\det(A-tI))$ directly but I've spent a while not getting anywhere and it seems cumbersome. Something tells me there is a more intelligent and elegant way. The rank of $A$ is only 2. Is there a way to use this?

Comment: What makes you say the rank is $2$?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2853981/find-the-eigenvalues-and-their-multiplicities-of-a-special-matrix?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eigenvalues of a matrix of $1$'s](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153457/eigenvalues-of-a-matrix-of-1s)

Answer (score 1):

1. Notice that $n$ is an eigenvalue with a certain eigenvector.
2. Notice that the rank is 1, so the kernel has dimension $n-1$.

This gives you a basis of eigenvectors ($n-1$ of them have eigenvalue 0).

Answer (score 1):

Actually the rank is $1$, not $2$.  Yes, there is a much better way: find the nonzero eigenvalue.  Hint: the eigenvector is $(1,\ldots,1)$.