# Confusion on Eigenvalues of Similar Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, self-learning

> *Please help me to identify where I went wrong:*

The completely reduced normal form of the real matrix $A=
        $\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}

is the following matrix $B=
        $\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
Clearly the eigenvalues of $B$ are $1,0,0$ so should the eigenvalues of $A$ since similar matrices have the same characteristic polynomial. But when I'm trying to formally evaluate the eigenvalues of $A$ the roots of $\chi_A$ become $0,0,3$.
        $$\begin{vmatrix}
        1-x & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1-x & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1-x \\
        \end{vmatrix}=0$$
$\implies (1-x)[(1-x)^2-1]-1[(1-x)-1]+1[1-(1-x)]=0$

$\implies (1-x)[x^2-2x]-1(-x)+x=0$

$\implies (1-x)[x^2-2x]+2x=0$

$\implies x^2-2x-x^3+2x^2+2x=0$

$\implies 3x^2-x^3=0$

$\implies x^2(3-x)=0$

So the eigenvalues of $A$ are $0,0,3.$

Comment: A more general question: [Eigenvalues of a matrix of $1$'s](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153457/eigenvalues-of-a-matrix-of-1s)

Comment: Do you want to compute [Jordan normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) or [reduced row echelon form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_row_echelon_form)? (Your [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263595/confusion-on-eigenvalues-of-similar-matrices/263599#comment575867_263599) seems to indicate that you were using some kind of row and column operations.)

Comment: What do you mean by "completely reduced normal form"? You must specify what operations are allowed. Every operation changes a matrix (a tautology) so if you want to apply operations you must know which class of matrix you want to remain in. Since here you want a _similarity_ class, the only operations possible are _conjugations_, I don't think you limited yourself to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment to the answer by jakncoke, I gather that you applied row and column operations to $A$. Those operations do not give you similar matrices, just [equivalent matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_equivalence). Therefore you can conclude that the *rank* of $A$ is equal to the rank of $B$ (indeed both are $1$) and **that is all**.  The matrices $A$ and $B$ are *not similar*. If you want the characteristic polynomial, you can do row and column operations on the polynomial matrix
$$
  XI_3-A = \pmatrix{X-1&-1&-1\\-1&X-1&-1\\-1&-1&X-1}
$$
before taking the determinant (the determinant is invariant under row and column operations if you take care to throw in a sign $-1$ for transpositions of two rows or two columns), but this is a lot harder than to do row and column operations on the matrix $A$. Deciding similarity is not so easy.

Answer (score 3):

Your reduced normal form for the matrix A is wrong.

Comment: Which can be easily checked using WolframAlpha: http://tinyurl.com/bmsfo5q

Comment: I'm still confused. I used $R_2-R_1\to C_2-C_1\to R_3-R_1 \to C_3-C_1.$

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Please help !

Comment: @SugataAdhya I don't know what more should be said here. The correct result for Jordan normal form is $\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ and not 
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$. (As you can check in the link I gave you.)

Comment: @SugataAdhya Are you using *both* row and column operations?

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Oh No !! I've confused **transpose** with **inverse**. Here $B=PAP^t$ for some non-singular $P$, not $B=PAP^{-1}$ for some non-singular $P$.

Comment: @hwhm: Ya, I was wrongly trying to find out congruent of $A$ !!