# Reducing a matrix of the form J-n*In, where J is the all-ones matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I reduce a matrix like this? The goal is to prove that the dimension of the generated space is 1. It's the matrix of the homogeneous system.

$\left( \begin{array}{cccccc}1-n&1&\dots &\dots&\dots&1 \\ 1 & 1-n & 1 & \dots & \dots & 1 \\ \vdots & 1 & \ddots & \ddots & & \vdots \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \vdots & \vdots && 1 & 1-n & 1 \\ 1 &1 & \dots & \dots & 1 & 1-n\end{array} \right)$.

Comment: What is $n$ ? = dimension of matrix ?

Comment: Yes. It comes from A-n*Id, where A is a matrix nxn of ones.

Comment: @Allonsy You may want to know, usually $J$ denotes the all-ones matrix.

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks for the info.

Comment: Let $\lambda$ be any eigenvalue of $J$, with corresponding eigenvector $x$. $Jx = \lambda x \Rightarrow (J - nI)x = Jx - nx = (\lambda - n)x$. Thus, every eigenvalue of $J - nI$ is $\lambda - n$ for every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $J$, and the eigenvectors are exactly the same.

Comment: Related: [Characteristic polynomial of a matrix of $1$'s](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153457/characteristic-polynomial-of-a-matrix-of-1s)

Answer (score 1):

The matrix diagonalizes to $$\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&0\\
0&-n&0&0\\
0&0&-n&0\\
0&0&0&-n\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1\\
\end{pmatrix}$
And if $X=\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
\vdots \\
x_n
\end{pmatrix}$ let $\sum X=x_1+\cdots x_n$.

Then we have $$AX=\sum X \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
\vdots \\
1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now consider the eigenvalue problem
$$(A-nI)X=\lambda X$$
or equivalently,
$$AX=(n+\lambda)  X=\sum X \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
\vdots \\
1
\end{pmatrix}$$
Now if $\lambda +n \neq 0$ then $X$ is a multiple of $\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
\vdots \\
1
\end{pmatrix}$ and we have that $\lambda +n=n$ so $\lambda$ is zero with an eigenspace of dimension one.
Otherwise $\lambda=-n$ and this has an eigenspace of dimension $n-1$
as can be easily checked the vectors $$\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
\vdots \\
0\\-1\\
0\\
\vdots\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$ are eigen vectors.

Finally it would be nice to check the minimal polynomial which should be $x(x+n)$

Comment: Mmmm I just found the characteristic polynomial, which is $(-1)^nx^n+(-1)^{n-1}nx^{n-1}=x^{n-1}((-1)^nx+(-1)^{n-1}n)$ which tell me that the roots are $x=0,x=n$ with multiplicity $n-1$ and $1$ respectively. So according to theory, $dim(ker(f-0Id))=dim(ker(f))$ should be $n-1$, and $dim(ker(f-nId))$ should be 1. Your solution seems right but it doesn't fit with what I've been told.

Comment: $(A-nI)(A-nI+nI)=A^2-nA==0$ so $x(x+n)$ is the minimal polynomial, you probably made a sign mistake in getting the characteristic poly. How did you calculate it anyway ?

Comment: With the determinant of A-xId. Turns out that is pretty simple, just $(-1)^nx^n+(-1)^{n-1}tr(A)x^{n-1}$ where tr(A) is the trace of A, which is n. All the other terms goes to 0.