# Are the matrix products $AB$ and $BA$ similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Given two matrices $A,B.$ On what conditions does $AB \sim BA$ hold?

Comment: Since it certainly holds if $A$ and $B$ commute, it would be nice to see an example where $AB\ne BA$ yet $AB \sim BA$.

Comment: Is is possible to prove that both share the same eigenvalues?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If $A$ is invertible, then $AB = A(BA)A^{-1}$ which shows that $AB$ and $BA$ are similar. Similar (no pun intended) proof if $B$ is invertible.

Answer (score 20):

$AB$ is conjugate to $BA$ if either $A$ or $B$ are invertible. If neither is the case, there are counterexamples: for example, it may be the case that $AB = 0$ while $BA \neq 0$. Explicitly, take
$$A = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right], B = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right].$$

We have $AB = A$ but $BA = 0$.

However, there is a salvage: $AB$ and $BA$ have the same characteristic polynomial. See [this blog post](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/ab-ba-and-the-spectrum/). (Short proof: this must hold if either $A$ or $B$ is invertible, and that condition is Zariski dense.)

Comment: Can you please provide with a reference regarding the case one of the matrices are invertiable ?

Comment: @Belgi If $A$ is invertible, and if $C=A^{-1}$, then $C(AB)C^{-1}=BA$ as you can check. Similarly, if $B$ is invertible, and if $C=B^{-1}$, then $C(BA)C^{-1}=AB$.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned already, if either of $A$ or $B$ is invertible (and both are the same size), we have
$$
\begin{align}
AB=A(BA)A^{-1}\quad&\mbox{if $A$ is invertible}\\
AB=B^{-1}(BA)B\quad&\mbox{if $B$ is invertible}
\end{align}
$$

However, [here is a short proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/94946) that even if $A$ is $m\times n$ and $B$ is $n\times m$, the characteristic polynomials of $AB$ and $BA$ differ only by a factor of $\lambda^{\large|n-m|}$.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is rather straightforward and I do not assume anything about $A$ and $B$, except that they are square.

I do so by showing that they have the same eigenvalues. If that is the case then $A=MJM^{-1}$ and $B=CJC^{-1}$ both share the same $J$ in their [Jordan form](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) and I take for granted that there exist some matrix $K$ such that $C=KM$, in order to have $B=KMJ(KM)^{-1}$.

So suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $AB$. Then $ABx=\lambda x$.

Premultiplying both sides by $B$, we get $BABx=(BA)(Bx)=λ(Bx)$, which shows that $\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue of $BA$.

Comment: Having the same eigenvalues doesn't mean they share a Jordan form. You should read the other answers, the result is false if $A$ and $B$ are non-invertible.

Comment: You're right, Ive just seen the counter example. I wrote it thinking they had a full set of eigenvalues, in which case that should be true of J.

Comment: Please note in my edit: the singular form of "matrices" is "matrix."