# Prove $A^TA$ is similar to $AA^T$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a nxn matrix in $R^{nxn}$.\
Prove  $A^TA$ is similar to $AA^T$.
Could anyone give me a hint on how to prove this? Any help will be appreciated.
(I have tried using eigenvectors but I don't know if those matrices are diagonalizable)

Comment: This link may contain what you are looking for: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421969/are-the-eigenvalues-of-a-top-a-equal-to-those-of-aa-top

Comment: That link actually mentions the fact (proven on m.se several times) that if $A$ and $B$ are two $n \times n$-matrices, then the two matrices $AB$ and $BA$ have the same characteristic polynomial. This does not yet imply that $AB$ and $BA$ are similar. However, when $B = A^T$ and the matrices are over $\mathbb{R}$, we actually know more: The matrices $A^T A$ and $AA^T$ are symmetric and thus diagonalizable. Diagonalizable matrices sharing a characteristic polynomial must be similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\lambda \neq 0$ is an eigenvalue of $AB$ with eigenvector $v$, then
$B(ABv)= (BA) Bv= \lambda Bv$ and so $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $BA$ (note that $Bv \neq 0$, otherwise $\lambda =0$).

Hence $AB$ and $BA$ have the same non zero eigenvalues.

Since $AA^T$ and $A^TA$ are real symmetric, they can be diagonalised with orthogonal matrices. It follows from the previous statement (since the geometric & algebraic multiplicities coincide) that $AA^T$ and $A^TA$ have
the same eigenvalues.

Hence we can find $U,V$ orthogonal such that
$AA^T U = U \Lambda$ and $A^TA V = V \Lambda$, where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal
matrix of the eigenvalues. Hence $A A^T = U V^T A^T A V U^T = (V U^T)^T A^T A (V U^T)$ and so $AA^T$ and $A^TA$ are similar.

Answer (score 4):

In case you are allowed to use singular value decomposition (SVD), Let $A=U\Sigma V^T$ be the SVD. Then $AA^T = U\Sigma^2 U^T$ and $A^TA = V\Sigma^2 V^T$. Since $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal, the similarity follows.

Answer (score 1):

Hint induction can be used or use the property $|A|=|A^{T}|$.