# Is it true that $\sigma(AB) =\sigma(BA) $.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-radius

Denote by $\sigma$ the spectral radius.

Is it true that $\sigma(AB) =\sigma(BA) $?

Edit: I am interested in the general case, i.e. $A$ is $n \times k$ and $B$ is $k \times n$.

Comment: Look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295515/spectral-radius-inequality.

Comment: @Ivan. Unfortunately the link you gave isn't really applicable, since I am not trying to bound the spectral radii of $A$ and $B$ separately.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/311362/1551), [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176034/are-the-matrix-products-ab-and-ba-similar) or [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124888/are-the-eigenvalues-of-ab-equal-to-the-eigenvalues-of-ba-citation-needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are square matrices of the same size, then the products $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues.

As was noted in comments by @Algebraic Pavel, the result still holds for rectangular matrices $A$ and $B$ (if the products $AB$ and $BA$ make sense). The non-zero eigenvalues of these products are the same.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to deal with the rectangular case. Does the result carry over?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are such that $AB$ and $BA$ make sense then the nonzero eigenvalues of $AB$ are same as the nonzero eigenvalue of $BA$ and vice versa. That is, $vu^T$ has a nonzero eigenvalue if and *only if* $u^Tv\neq 0$. Therefore, the result *carries over* to the rectangular matrices.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel thank you for this catch, I somehow mixed the norm and the spectral radius.

Answer (score 1):

$\sigma_p$ denotes here the set of eigenvalues. For matrices it is the same as $\sigma$ (spectrum).
A $R^{m\times n}$ matrix is a linear operator $R^n\to R^m$; similarly for $C^{m\times n}$, so the following answers to you.

**Theorem**. Let $X,Y$ be vector spaces (with the same scalar field $R$ or $C$). Let $A:X\to Y$ and $B:Y\to X$ be linear.

(a) Then $\sigma_p(AB)\setminus\{0\} = \sigma_p(BA)\setminus\{0\}$.

(b) If both $X$ and $Y$ are $n$-dimensional, $n<\infty$,
then $\sigma_p(AB) = \sigma_p(BA)$.

**Proof**: (a) Let $0\ne t\in \sigma_p(AB)$. Then $AB y=ty$ for some $y\in Y\setminus\{0\}$.
Right-multiply by $B$ to get $BA(By)=t(By)$.
Thus, $t\in\sigma_p(BA)$ (because $By\ne0$, as else $0=AB y=ty$).
Therefore, $\sigma_p(AB)\setminus\{0\} \subset \sigma_p(BA)\setminus\{0\}$.
Exchange $A$ with $B$ to get $\sigma_p(AB)\setminus\{0\} \supset \sigma_p(BA)\setminus\{0\}$.

(b) Assume $\dim X=n=\dim Y$. If $ABy=0$ for some $y\ne 0$, then $A$ or $B$ is singular
(as $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$);
hence so is then $BA$. Thus, $0\in\sigma_p(AB) \Rightarrow 0\in\sigma_p(BA)$. Exchange $A,B$. QED.

**Remarks.**
(a) By the above proof, (a) holds for bounded and even for unbounded operators (as long as they are defined on the whole space, as assumed in the theorem) over infinite-dimensional vector spaces.

(b1) Claim (b) is not true for non-square matrices.
For example, $0\in\sigma(AB)\setminus\sigma_p(BA)$ if $A^T=(1,0)=B$,
as then $BA=1$, $AB=(1,0; 0,0)$.

(b2) Claim (b) is not true for $n=\infty$.
For example, let L, R be the left and right shifts on $R^N$, the set of sequences $(x_1,x_2,\cdots)$. Then $LR=I$ but $RL(1,0,0,0,\ldots)=R0=0$, so $0\in\sigma_p(RL)\setminus\sigma_p(LR)$.

(c) In the infinite-dimensional case, usually $\sigma_p$ denotes the eigenvalues and $\sigma$ is typically a bigger set (in many books all $t$ for which $t-A$ is not a boundedly invertible bijection), but for (square) matrices $\sigma=\sigma_p$.

Better answers and more information can be found here (e.g., for matrices the eigenvalues are the same even counting multiplicities, which would not require much extra work in the above proof, either):
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/124903/426834

Comment: How do you know that if $t \in \sigma (AB)$ then $t$ is an eigenvalue of $AB\ $? This is not necessarily true for operators defined on infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces.

Comment: The first sentence in my answer said that I define $\sigma$ as the set of eigenvalues. I did that to help those familiar with matrices only. But as you proved that this causes misinterpretations, I now changed it to operator language, i.e., used $\sigma_p$, instead.