# Eigen-values of $AB$ and $BA$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A,B \in M(n,\mathbb{C})$ be two $n\times n$ matrices. I would like know how to prove that eigen-value of $AB$ is the same as the eigen-values of $BA$.

Comment: Is this homework? what have you tried?

Comment: A [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/94926/11619). Not an exact duplicate, because there it was assumed that $B$ is invertible. Studying the answers given there will get you started anyway (more or less along the lines of Matt Pressland's +1 answer).

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** let $v$ be an eigenvector of $AB$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. What is $BABv$?

Comment: I think you mean $Bv$

Comment: @sun Nope, although that would also be a good question to ask. Answering the question I asked should lead to an answer to your suggested modification, if I've understood correctly.

Comment: right. I initially thought you wanna ask what's the eigenvector of BA.

Answer (score 3):

you can prove $|\lambda I-AB|=|\lambda I-BA|$ by computing the determinant of following
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
I & A \\
B & I \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
in two diffeerent ways.