# Relation between eigen values of $AB$ and $BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let say $A \in \mathbb{F}^{n\times m}$ and $B \in \mathbb{F}^{m\times n}$. I am wondering weather there is any standard result stating the relationship between eigen values of $AB$ and $BA$ matrices.

I know that eigen values are same for $AB$ and $BA$ when both $A$ and $B$ are square matrices. But in a general setup, we can not use the result that- $\det(AB) = \det(BA)$.

Comment: Do you understand the hint given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/262035/11619)? A subtlety (partly hidden in that hint) is that $AB$ and $BA$ only share non-zero eigenvalues.

Comment: One is an $m\times m$ matrix and the other is an $n \times n$ matrix. One has $m$ eigenvalues while the other has $n$ eigenvalues. At least, from the trace, you can see that the sum of 2 sets of eigenvalues are the same.

Comment: Actually, I was going through one pdf. They also mentioned the same thing, but no proof was given in it. Thanks for sharing the link. I will go through it. @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: Hi, @mastrok , yes that is obvious, but I think we can say something more stronger than that as it is mentioned in Jyrki 's comment.

Comment: Look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378868/the-relationship-between-eigenvalues-of-matrices-xy-and-yx/378888#378888) or the second answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94926/how-to-show-if-lambda-is-an-eigenvalue-of-ab-1-then-lambda-is-an-e?lq=1).