# Finding determinant of a simple matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Can someone please explain how to compute the determinant of $J_n - I_n$ where $j_n$ it a matrix of ones?

E.g. for $n=5$ we get the following matrix

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & 1 & 1 &1 &1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 &1 &1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 &1 &1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 &0 &1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 &1 &0 \end{array} \right)$$

By computing it for the first few $n$'s it seems to be $(-1)^{n+1}(n-1)$ but I couldn't prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us put

$$
D =\left|\begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & 1 & 1 &1 &1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 &1 &1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 &1 &1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 &0 &1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 &1 &0 
\end{array} \right|
$$

Performing the operation $L_1 \gets \sum_{k=1} L_k$ and putting $m=n-1$, we obtain

$$
D =\left|\begin{array}{ccccc}
m & m & m &m &m \\
1 & 0 & 1 &1 &1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 &1 &1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 &0 &1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 &1 &0 
\end{array} \right|=
m\left|\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 1 & 1 &1 &1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 &1 &1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 &1 &1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 &0 &1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 &1 &0 
\end{array} \right|
$$

Performing $L_j \gets L_j-L_1$ for all $j\gt 1$, we obtain

$$
D =
m\left|\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 1 & 1 &1 &1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 &0 &0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 &0 &0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 &-1 &0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 &0 &-1 \\
\end{array} \right|
=m(-1)^m
$$

as you expected.

Comment: +1 Eventhough this is a repeated question, this answer stands up by its clearity and simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that $J_n=(1,\cdots,1)^T(1,\cdots,1)$ and robjohn's comment in the following: [How to show if $ \lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $AB^{-1}$, then $ \lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $ B^{-1}A$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94926/how-to-show-if-lambda-is-an-eigenvalue-of-ab-1-then-lambda-is-an-e)

Comment: Blatantly missed it, robjohn's comment can be replaced by http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_theorem

Comment: @Guest, thank you for pointing out this. This formula is very handy for calculating spectra.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the first row from the rows below it, then add row 2 through $n$ to the first row, to get a triangular matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Row addition doesn't alter the determinant. Subtracting the first row from the others, then adding each other row to the first, you'll get a lower triangular matrix, whose determinant is simply the product of its diagonal entries.