# $\det(A+I)=1+\text{tr}(A)$, if $\text{rank}(A)=1$ proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-rank

This was the starred problem in our linear algebra class.

So I understand that if a $k$-by-$k$ matrix has rank $1$, it means that all rows are linearly dependant on lets say the first one. So if I have a matrix, I can write it as:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & c_1*a_1 & c_2*a_1 & \cdots& c_k*a_1 \\
a_2 & c_1*a_2 & c_2*a_2 & \cdots & c_k*a_2 \\
a_3 & c_1*a_3 & c_2*a_3 & \cdots & c_k*a_3 \\
\vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \ddots  & \vdots\\
a_k & c_1*a_k & c_2*a_k & \cdots& c_k*a_k \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So if I write A+I:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1+1 & c_1*a_1 & c_2*a_1 & \cdots& c_k*a_1 \\
a_2 & c_1*a_2+1 & c_2*a_2 & \cdots & c_k*a_2 \\
a_3 & c_1*a_3 & c_2*a_3+1 & \cdots & c_k*a_3 \\
\vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \ddots  & \vdots\\
a_k & c_1*a_k & c_2*a_k & \cdots& c_k*a_k+1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

And $\det(A+I)=a_1+1$, since I can subtract $c_n$ ($n=1,2,3,\dots k$) times the first column from all the other columns and I am left with a upper triangular matrix.

So I would get $a_1+1=1+\text{tr}(A)$ and $a_1=\text{tr}(A)$, but this can't be right? I can't figure out where I am going wrong. Any help?

Of course I read the other one, but fine, no help from here.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429055/mboxranka-1-implies-detai-mboxtracea1)?

Comment: Actually, if you subtract $c_k$ times the first column from the other columns, the resulting matrix might not be upper triangular, since you haven't changed the first column.