# Linear Algebra question help.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, trace

I am having difficulty in proving the following question.

[$\mbox{rank}(A)=1$ implies $\det(A+I)=\mbox{trace}(A)+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429055/mboxranka-1-implies-detai-mboxtracea1)

My thought is det$(A+I)$ implies that eigenvalue of $A$ is $-1$ and since rank of $A$ is $1$ determinate of all minor of order $n-1$ is zero so in characteristic polynomial expansion formula we get $det(A+I)=(-1)^n(\lambda^n+trace(A))=1+trace(A)$.

Is my approach correct? Could you please write the solution according to the hints given in this question? Thank you.

Comment: If $A$ has rank 1 it can be written as $u v^T$ for some vectors $u,v$.

Comment: How can $\det(A+I)$ imply anything?

Comment: It may be wrong. It is just what I was thinking.

Comment: I want to solve this question according to the hints given in the question.

Comment: Is A assumed to be diagonalisable?

Comment: @klirk No......

Comment: I edited my answer in order to comment on your proposed strategy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that for any square matrix, its trace is the sum of its eigenvalues and its determinant is the product of the eigenvalues. (The eigenvalues could be complex).

Further, if $t$ is an eigenvalue of a Matrix $M$, then $1+t$ is an eigenvalue of $M+I$:

$$\det [(A+I)-(1+t) I] = \det [A-tI]=0$$

---

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$-matrix of rank $1$.

Since $A$ has rank $1$, it has the eigenvalues $0$ with multiplicity $n-1$ and $\lambda \neq 0$ with mulitplicity $1$.

Thus we get $\det (A) = 1^{n-1} \cdot(\lambda+1)= \lambda+1$ and $\operatorname{tr}(A) = (n-1)\cdot 0+\lambda= \lambda $

This implies the claim.

---

Edit: (This is more like a comment, but too long)

I see, you want to use that for $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $M$
$$0= \det(M-\lambda I) = \sum_{i=0}^n  b_i (-\lambda)^{n-1}   $$
with $b_i$ the sum of all principal minors of order $i$.
In particular $b_0:=1$, $b_1 = \operatorname{tr} M$, $a_n= \det M$.

So for $M=A+I$:

$$ 0= \det (A+I-\lambda I) = (-\lambda)^n + (-\lambda)^{n-1}\operatorname{tr}(A+I)+\det(A+I) + \dots ,$$
and thus for $\lambda=1: $

$$ 0=\det(A) = (-1)^n (1-\operatorname{tr}(A+I)+ \dots) +\det(A+I) + .$$
This implies $$\det(A+I)= (-1)^{n+1} (1-\operatorname{tr}(A) -n+\dots) $$

But I don't see how we can use $\operatorname{rk} A=1$ in order to calculate the remaining summands.