# Prove that the determinant of a householder matrix is -1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I understand that a householder matrix has eigenvalues of either 1 or -1, however I isn't clear to me why the determinant is -1. Clearly the determinant is equal to the product of the eigenvalues so there must be an odd number of eigenvalues that are -1. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

A Householder matrix has eigenvalues $\pm 1$. To see this, notice that if $u$ is orthogonal to the vector $v$ which was used to create the reflector, then $Pu = u$, i.e., $1$ is an eigenvalue of multiplicity $n-1$, since there are $n-1$ independent vectors orthogonal to $v$. Also, notice $Pv = -v$, and so $-1$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity $1$. So, the determinant of a Householder matrix is $-1$, since the determinant of a matrix is the product of its eigenvalues.

Comment: Why is 1 an eigenvalue with multiplicity n-1? What I mean to say is why does it not have multiplicity n-3 for example?

Comment: This is because there are $n-1$ independent vectors orthogonal to $v$.

Comment: Can you please explain why there are n-1 independent vectors orthogonal to v? Thank you

Comment: because $\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{span}\{v\})+\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{span}\{v\}^{\perp})=n$

Comment: to prove $dim(span\{v\}^{\perp})) = n-1$ we can use rank nullity theorem and define n by n matrix A having 0 in all elements except the last row is $v^T$ so now rank(A) = 1 (asssuming v is non-zero) so null(A) = n-1 but null space of A is the set of all vectors orthogonal to v so we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Algebraically, this follows from the following two facts:

1. Every Householder matrix can be written as $I-2vv^\ast$ for some unit vector $v$.
2. For vectors $x$ and $y$, we have the [formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420198/proving-the-relation-deti-xyt-1-xty) $\det(I-xy^\ast)=1-y^\ast x$.

Comment: Can you show how the second fact produces -1 when x is v and y is v*.

Comment: @user96723 Huh? Why? Compare $I-xy^\ast$ and $I-\color{red}{2}vv^\ast$ again. What choices of $x$ and $y$ are sensible?

Comment: Note that $v$ must have unit norm (so that $v^*v=1$).

Comment: @PavelJiranek Yes. I forgot to mention that. Thanks for pointing it out.