# Determinant of unit identity matrix is equal to the trace plus one of that matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am trying to show that

$$\det \left(I_{n} + 
\begin{bmatrix} 
a_{1} \\ a_{2} \\ \vdots \\ a_{n}
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}b_{1}&b_{2}&\cdots&b_n \end{bmatrix} \right) 
= 1 + \sum_{m=1}^n a_{m}b_{m}$$

I know I have to use the fact that 
$$\ M=QDQ^{T}$$

I can see that with a diagonal matrix its determinant its equal to its trace, but I am having a hard time figuring out what to do with that identity and that 1?

Comment: Where I_{n} is the unit identity matrix of dimesion nxn

Comment: Apparently, either $\ \begin{bmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\\vdots\\a_n\end{bmatrix}\ $ should be $\ \begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\\vdots\\b_n\end{bmatrix}\ $, or $\ \begin{bmatrix}a_1&a_2&\dots&a_n\end{bmatrix}\ $ should be $\ \begin{bmatrix}b_1&b_2&\dots&b_n\end{bmatrix}\ $.  Which is it? While the answer is the same in either case, its derivation will be slightly different.

Comment: I have fixed the second vector, it should be the "b" vector

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Assuming the problem is to find the determinant of the matrix $\ I_n + ab^\top\ $, the determinant can be expressed as a product of that matrix's eigenvalues.  One of its eigenvectors is $\ a\ $. What is the corresponding eigenvalue?  There are $\ n-1\ $ eigenvectors that are perpendicular to $\ b\ $.  What are the corresponding eigenvalues?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420198/proving-the-relation-deti-xyt-1-xty

Comment: I am not sure how to approach this solving for the eigenvalues. Just trying for a as a 2x1 and b as a 1x2, and adding the identity matrix, it becomes messy, not sure I can zero out the off bottom diagonal. The link above helped me a bit, specially Marc's and leonbloy's suggestions, i just cant put the pieces together.

Comment: $$\left(I_n + ab^\top\right)a = \left(1+ b^\top a\right)a\  ,$$
so the corresponding eigenvalue is $\ 1+ b^\top a\ $.

If $\ v\perp b\ $, then
$$\left(I_n + ab^\top\right)v = v\ ,$$
so the corresponding eigenvalue is $1$.  The product of the eigenvalues (i.e. the determinant) is therefore $\ 1^{n-1}\left(1+ b^\top a\right)=1+\sum_\limits{m=1}^n a_m b_m\ $.