# Determinant of 4x4 w/ all entries unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, laplace-expansion

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

> If $A$ is the matrix
>   $$
> A = \begin{bmatrix}
> a   & b   & c   & d+1\\
> a   & b   & c+1 & d  \\
> a   & b+1 & c   & d  \\
> a+1 & b   & c   & d  
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>   find the determinant of $B = 3A^5 A^t A^{-1}.$

I see that $\det\left( A^t A^{-1} \right) = 1$ but I'm having difficulty computing $\det\left(3A^5\right)$.  Laplace expansion seems like it will be too time consuming as this is an exam review question(I don't think we would be expected to do Laplace expansion with a 4x4 matrix on an exam).  And my apologies for the link.  The site won't let me post images as I am new here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, we only need to calculate $\det{A}$. For the first 3 rows, substract the next one. The determinant is unchanged and we get
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 
 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
a+1 & b & c & d
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Then expand the last column. And we get
\begin{align*}
\det{A} &= d\cdot(1) +(-1)\cdot \begin{vmatrix} 0 & -1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & 0 \\ a+1 & b & c
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=d-\left( c\cdot (-1) + \begin{vmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ a+1& b \end{vmatrix} \right)\\
&= d +c -(-b - (a+1))\\
&=a+b+c+d+1.
\end{align*}
For the determinant of $3A^5 A^\top A^{-1}$ just use that $\det$ is multiplicative. That is, $\det (3A^5 A^\top A^{-1})=3^4 \det (A^5)\det (A^\top)\det (A^{-1})=3^4 (a+b+c+d+1)^5$.

Answer (score 3):

Flipping the matrix left and right, the determinant remains unchanged (because the matrix has an even number of columns) but the matrix becomes $I+ev^T$, where $e=(1,1,1,1)^T$ and $v=(d,c,b,a)^T$. Now you may use [Sylvester's determinant theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/420198) to obtain $\det(A)=\det(I+ev^T)=1+v^Te=1+a+b+c+d$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

- The rule is $\det(AB) = \det(A) \cdot \det(B)$.Hence, $\det(A^2) = \det(A)^2$, for example.
- Multiplying every entry in a matrix by a constant is equivalent to multiplying the matrix by a diagonal matrix, with all entries equal to that constant, i.e. $5A = (5I)A$.

Can you finish now?

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Yes I see that if I can compute the Det of A I can raise that value to the 5th power and multiply that by 3^4.  My issue is computing the Det of A.  I've tried manipulating the matrix in an attempt to get entries only on the diagonal but I'm having no luck.

Comment: @user734624 Apply Gaussian Elimination, subtracting one row from another does not change the determinant. Eliminate a couple and then use cofactor expansion,