# best way to show tr(AB) = tr(BA) for non square A and b matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace

I have matrices $A \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times m}$ and $B \in \mathbb{K}^{m \times n}$

What is the best way to prove that tr(AB) = tr(BA). I found a prove in Matrix Analysis by Horn and Johnson, but they only prove it if $n \leq m$.

Comment: The same proof will apply. I don't know how it's done in Horn and Johnson but the standard proof is just a computation from the definition of the trace and the definition of matrix multiplication. Unless I'm missing something, there's really nothing gained by assuming an order relation between $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Use equation $(4)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/94946) along with the fact that the trace is the negative of the coefficient of the penultimate term in the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either you have $n\leq m$ or $m\leq n$. If it is the latter, exchange $n$ with $m$ and $A$ with $B$, and the same proof works.

Comment: I could have thought of that. thanks

Comment: Story of my life.